# Windows 8 HDD unable to boot, later unable to read from Windows7 machine as well

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, freeze, formatting, windows-8-upgrade

On a Samsung Windows 8 machine after some time I was not able to boot. Checking the BIOS shows that HDD is frozen. Them machine takes lots of time to boot. 
Saying this I would like some suggestions if its still possible to get it working without formatting?

Later on I placed the HDD to my old Windows 7 machine. It did not appear as online initially as in picture 1,and Windows 7 does not seem to recognize this HDD but still shows the right size.

later I initialized the drive to online seems it will let me format `figure 2`, but wanted to get suggestions before formatting.

I am not sure, what might have gone wrong?

I am looking for a way to make it work.  I will be running Windows 8 on this machine. I may go from Windows 7 installation to upgrade or directly Windows 8.  I think upgrading from Windows 7 to 8 would be is cheaper.

please suggest, how would you deal in this kind of scenario?

[image: image 1 and 2 together]

Comment: The cost to upgrade to Windows 7 to Windows 8 is more in the general sense since that original Windows 7 license cannot be used on another computer.  As for the problem with the hdd looks like you have hardware failure, at this point, the data is likely gone.

Answer (score 1):

I would **run a test on the drive** before installing anything on it. If there truly is an issue with a bad sector or if the freezing problem might recur due to something physically wrong with it, I would replace it.

I use [Seatools](http://www.seagate.com/support/downloads/seatools/) which can be run from Windows or from a bootable disk. You could also use [Hiren's boot](http://www.hirensbootcd.org/download/) if you're looking for a better selection of weapons.

If you don't find any errors, I'd safe it would be safe to install Windows on the drive but image it on a regular basis ([Acronis TrueImage](http://www.acronis.com/homecomputing/products/trueimage/#overview)). If the issue occurs again I would just assume it's faulty and replace it.